# Verifying Mx(0)=1

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

A pdf of random variable  X is f(x)=1/2, support of X=[-1,1]

I am supposed to verify Mx(0)=1. How do we verify this? I found mgf of X: (e^t - e^-t)/2t

Also, when you take the first derviate of mgf, it should give you expected value of X based on definition but I am not getting that either. Expected value of X is 0. I couldn't verify this with mgf derivative.Please help!

Comment: $E[\exp(0\times X)]=E[\exp(0)]=E(1)=1$.

Comment: Omg. Is this how you verify it? Is there any other way? Also, how about the second part of the question? Expected value of X is 0. I couldn't verify this with mgf derivative.

Comment: I think it is shown using Le'Hospital rule. Because it makes numerator and denominator 0.

Comment: Why makes things complicated when you can evaluate $M_X(0)$ directly?

Answer (score 1):

Let $M_X$ be the MGF of $X$. Then, by definition,
$$
M_X(0)=E[\exp(0\times X)]=E[\exp(0)]=E(1)=1
$$
As for $E(X)=0$:
$$
E(X)=\int_{-1}^1xf(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1x/2dx=\int_0^1\frac{x}{2}+\int_{-1}^0\frac{x}{2}dx.
$$
By a change of variable $u=-x$, we have 
$$
\int_{-1}^0\frac{x}{2}dx=\int_{1}^0\frac{-u}{2}(-du)=\int_1^0\frac{u}{2}du=-\int_0^1\frac{u}{2}du=-\int_0^1\frac{x}{2}dx.
$$
Do you see why $E(X)=0$?